# How do I turn on hidden features in the apple store connect in review process?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a mobile game that I developed with swift. I show some features and views in the next levels. that is, the first installer of the game will not be able to use those views and features. My question is, how can I open these features and views during the app store connect in review process. they will want to see their content.

Turning on/off remotely with firebase remote config. If I do this, existing users will also open. How can I make the views appear only during the in review process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is authentication, create a user with more or less, admin power, such that you give apple the user to authenticate with and they will see the hidden content, otherwise

In your code, with the help of remote config, authenticate any new users anonymously and grant anyone who is authenticated to see the hidden content.

This means when the reviewer gets this specific version of your app, they will be the only one authenticated and therefore see the hidden content and when the review process is done, deactivate the functionality in remote config

Comment: thanks. If they accept it like this, I will give a facebook user information and solve it. When you log in from that account, everything will be open.